# How can I tell if STDIN is connected to a terminal in Perl?

Tags: perl, terminal, stdin

How can I tell if STDIN is connected to a terminal in Perl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (-t *STDIN) {
  # stdin is connected
} else {
  # stdin is not connected
}
```

I usually use this in conjunction with `-t *STDOUT`, to find out if I'm running from an interactive shell, or from cron, to enable more output.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between `-t STDIN`, `-t *STDIN`, and `-t \*STDIN`?

Answer (score 12):

You might also be interested in [IO::Interactive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO-Interactive) to figure out if Perl thinks it is interacting with a user. Simply being connected to a tty doesn't mean the user is going to see what you do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use *tty*:

```
[root@server] ~> tty
/dev/pts/0
[root@server] ~> echo y | tty
not a tty
```

But it is not very pretty...